# Dojo and Dijit reference for all properties

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I was experimenting with Dojo and Dijit in the past days and I find it quite interesting. I was however trying to find a reference or an API doc that helps me understand all the properties I can assign to widgets and containers.

For example a Tab with a Save Icon will be like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Group Two" data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconSave'">
```

Now, where can I find what to put in the "data-dojo-props" property? Where can I find for example all the list of icons?

My main question would be for example on how to create a vertical menubar, but beyond odd examples scattered here and there, the api reference is not much helpful...

Any help? Am I missing something here?

Comment: ahhh, unfortunately one of the drawbacks of being a dojo developer... I haven't found this in the last 8 months...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of situation, the trick is learning how to convert between the programmatic Javascript style and the declarative HTML style (and sometimes also between the old declarative style, without data).

For the new declarative style, basically the only "real" argument now is `data-dojo-props` and it consists of an object that will be passed to the widget constructor.

```js
//programatic style
new dijit.myWidget({foo:'a', bar:'b'});
```

```html
//declarative style
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.myWidget" data-dojo-props="foo:'a', bar:'b'"></div>
```

You can find what properties an widget accepts by checking the corresponding widget documentation and looking for either declarative or programmatic examples (now that we know how to convert between them). If that is not enough, you can also check the source code - it is usually very well commented and is where *api.dojotoolkit.org* gets its data from anyway.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but apparently the best answer. Anyway, the API documentation at http://dojotoolkit.org/api/ does not mention any constructor parameters that can be used. The reference, on the other hand, just shows examples where you can pick up some of the properties but not everything...

Comment: @Tallmaris: The api used to show all the properties. I guess something must have got bugged in the 1.6 to 1.7 transition. (The source is still the ultimate source though)

Comment: You are right, browsing the 1.6 API shows a lot more stuff. :/